# append missing names to end of a groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

I am working on a report automation task I used groupby function which yielded a table

```
function_d= {"AvgLoadCur": 'mean'}
newdf=df.groupby(['sitename']).agg(function_d)
```

> ```
> sitename                       AvgLoadCur
> Biocon-SEZD-66/11KV SS 11          23.0
> Biocon-SEZD-GT 1 120V DC           24.2
> Biocon-SEZD-GT 2 120V DC           23.9
> Biocon-SEZD-PLC 24V                21.4
> ```

df contains only 4 sitenames hence groupby table also contains only those four how can I append the missing two sitename which are stored in another dataframe site['sitename']

```
sitename
Biocon-SEZD-GT 1 120V DC
Biocon-SEZD-GT 2 120V DC
Biocon-SEZD-SCADA UPS
Biocon-SEZD-66/11KV SS 11
Biocon-SEZD-PLC 24V DC
BIOCON SEZ-HT PANEL 220 V
```

The Final Dataframe should look like

> ```
> sitename                       AvgLoadCur
> Biocon-SEZD-66/11KV SS 11          23.0
> Biocon-SEZD-GT 1 120V DC           24.2
> Biocon-SEZD-GT 2 120V DC           23.9
> Biocon-SEZD-PLC 24V                21.4
>   Biocon-SEZD-HT PANEL 220 V          --
>   Biocon-SEZD-SCADA UPS               --
> ```

In short how to append elements which are not present in a groupby table from another dataframe

groupby table:

```
Fruit  Price
apple    34
```

A df table

```
Fruit
--------
apple 
orange
```

Final groupby table

```
Fruit  Price
apple    34
orange   --
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this would answer your question:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['apple',1],['orange',2]],columns=['Fruit','Price'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['guava','apple','orange'],columns=['Fruit'])
for value in df2['Fruit'].values:
    if value not in df['Fruit'].values:
        df = df.append({'Fruit':value,'Price':'--'},ignore_index=True)
df
```

Output

```
    Fruit   Price
0   apple   1
1   orange  2
2   guava   --
```

Comment: try to avoid looping, you can use `merge` or `concat` with many vectorised functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can first merge your dataframe and then groupby.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit': {0: 'apple'}, 'Price': {0: 34}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit': {0: 'apple', 1: 'orange'}})

(
    pd.merge(df,df2,on='Fruit',how='right')
    .groupby('Fruit')
    .agg(avg=('Price', 'mean'))
    .reset_index()
)

    Fruit   avg
0   apple   34.0
1   orange  NaN
```

Comment: @Harish Reddy this should be the accepted answer, try to avoid looping in pandas when possible